# Can someone help me solving an issue with Vader Sentiment in R?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, vader

I am performing an analysis on a dataset of tweets on R with Vader package but I am facing an issue. After computing correctly the score for some tweets, the operation interrupts and this error is retrieved:

```
Error in if (min(names(dicCheck)) == names(dicCheck[grep(checkMe, dicCheck)])) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I don't know if it is a problem with the data itself or if it is a problem of the function.

I am using this code

```
for (i in 1:length(Data$tweet)){
    get_vader(Data$tweet[i]) %>%
      as.numeric(unlist(.)) %>%
      .[length(.)-4] ->Data$score_vader[i]
}
```

If someone can help me I would be very grateful!

Comment: You could work a `try()` or `tryCatch()` function in there to prevent errors when you get NULL or when `length(.)-4` makes no sense. Since you ran a loop, you could check the `i` where you get the error and work out what `get_vader(Data$tweet[i])` returns.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and I managed to overcome the problem thanks to a `tryCatch()` function. The problem was with `get_vader(data$tweet[i])` function and not with the subsequent lines.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I managed to overcome the error with a `tryCatch()` function. The problem is due to the nature of the text analyzed the function. To overcome this problem the code I used is:

```
for (i in 1:length(Data$tweet)){
  Loop_Error <- F
  tryCatch({ 
    get_vader(Data$tweet[i]) %>%
      as.numeric(unlist(.)) %>%
      .[length(.)-4] ->Data$score_vader[i]
  }, error = function(e){
        Loop_Error <<- T})
  if (Loop_Error){
    Data$score_vader[i] <- "Error"
  }
}
```